# Jquery Slick carousel not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the slick carousel center mode example  but i am unable to run it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.. Can someone show me how to make it work?1

[Slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="center">
        <div>your content 1</div>
        <div>your content 2</div>
        <div>your content 3</div>
        <div>your content 4</div>
        <div>your content 5</div>
        <div>your content 6</div>
        <div>your content 7</div>
        <div>your content 8</div>
        <div>your content 9</div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.center').slick({
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '60px',
                slidesToShow: 3,
                responsive: [
                  {
                      breakpoint: 768,
                      settings: {
                          arrows: false,
                          centerMode: true,
                          centerPadding: '40px',
                          slidesToShow: 3
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      breakpoint: 480,
                      settings: {
                          arrows: false,
                          centerMode: true,
                          centerPadding: '40px',
                          slidesToShow: 1
                      }
                  }
                ]
            });

        });
    </script>



</body>
```

Comment: Do you have the slick folder in your root directory? If not, I would recommend including the files via the jsDelivr CDN

Answer (score 0):

You maybe arent including the slick js and css files, use CDN instead, every thing else looks fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```